# What is the ideal public nxt.properties config file for a public facing node for NXT / Ardor?

Tags: nodes, nxt, full-node, ardor

I can't find a template for nxt.properties when running a public node. Is there a public template I can just copy and paste and make some adjustments for NXT / Ardor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the following entries still necessary:

```
nxt.uiServerHost=0.0.0.0
nxt.uiServerCORS=true
nxt.uiSSL=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is what I use for a public node for Ardor. Some of the lines are commented out, you can enable them if you wish.

```
# Can also specify networks in CIDR notation, e.g. 192.168.1.0/24.
#nxt.allowedBotHosts=127.0.0.1; localhost; [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1];
nxt.allowedBotHosts=*; localhost; [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1];


# Host interface on which to listen for http/json API request, default localhost only.
# Set to 0.0.0.0 to allow the API server to accept requests from all network interfaces.
#nxt.apiServerHost=127.0.0.1
nxt.apiServerHost=0.0.0.0


# Hosts from which to allow NRS user interface requests, if enabled. Set to * to allow all.
#nxt.allowedUserHosts=127.0.0.1; localhost; [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1];
nxt.allowedUserHosts=*; localhost; [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1];


# Host interface for NRS user interface server, default localhost only.
# Set to 0.0.0.0 to allow the UI to be accessed on all network interfaces.
#nxt.uiServerHost=127.0.0.1
nxt.uiServerHost=0.0.0.0


nxt.isTestnet=false


nxt.apiServerCORS=true
nxt.uiServerCORS=true

#nxt.apiServerPort=27876


#nxt.apiServerSSLPort=27876
nxt.maxPrunableLifetime=-1
nxt.includeExpiredPrunable=true
nxt.adminPassword=SET_YOUR_OWN

# The default account is used, to automatically login to the wallet during startup
#nxt.defaultDesktopAccount=ASDFASDF

#nxt.uiSSL=true
#nxt.apiSSL=true

nxt.myPlatform=xxx0000
```

Comment: Should set nxt.isTestnet=false if you are running on the main network.

Comment: Make sure to **apt install OPENJDK-8-JDK** as openjdk-11-jdk doesn't work